# moment js issue with french format

Tags: date, format, momentjs

**ACTUAL ISSUE:**
am using momentjs and below code to validate date format

```
date = moment(dateVal, fmt);
```

if format is YYYY-MM-DD, and if dateVal is 2017-04, then date value is not coming as null. moment function is sending 2017-04-01 as the date back instead of "invalid date" or null. how do i change the code for the moment to show invalid date.

**i tried this**

```
date = moment(dateVal, fmt, true);
```

but for some reason when i use this, isValid is always coming as false, even when i send valid date and format.  for eg, 1/4/2017 with format MM/DD/YYYY is giving error with date = moment(dateVal, fmt, true)

here is my code

```
 var CustomDateValidate = function (dateVal, fmt) {
    var date = null;
    if (dateVal !== null && dateVal !== undefined) {
        fmt = defaultFor(fmt, getHiddenData().dateFormatJavascriptMoment); // here for en the fmt will be "MM/DD/YYYY" and for fr the fmt will be "YYYY-MM-DD"

        date = moment(dateVal, fmt, true);
        if (!(date.isValid())) {
            date = null;
        }
        //else 
        if (date.year().toString().length < 4) {
            date = null;
        } else if (date.toString().toLowerCase() === 'invalid date') {
            date = null;
        } else if (date._i.toString().length > 10) {
            date = null;
        }
    }
    return date;
```

plz help.

Comment: What is your problem? `date = moment(dateVal, fmt, true);` gives `Invalid date` for `2017-04` and `YYYY-MM-DD` as expected. What do you mean with _when i use this am always getting error_? Please edit your question explaining better your problem, consider adding a snippet or a fiddle showing your issue.

Comment: am getting error when i send 1/4/2017 and format as mm/dd/yyyy when i use date = moment(dateVal, fmt, true)

Comment: Format strings are case sensitive.  `mm` is minutes, `dd` is an abreviation for the day of the week, and `yyyy` is not a valid token.  Did you mean `MM/DD/YYYY` ? Please edit your question to give code, including string values, that produces the problem.